# NodeJs Hapi Framework Doc Generator not working

Tags: node.js

I am using the nodejs hapi framework. So far it has been great and I wanted to try out the document generator. I know it says that it still might change but the code on their site does not work for me (http://spumko.github.com/resource/api/#documentation-generator):

```
// Create Hapi server
var http = new Hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 8080);

var loutConfig = { plugin: { indexTemplatePath: './templates' } };
http.plugin().require('lout', loutConfig, function () {
    http.start(); 
});
```

This throws a type error complaining that plugin() is not a function of http (the hapi server).

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the parentheses when referencing http.plugin, like so:

```
// Create Hapi server
var http = new Hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 8080);

var loutConfig = { plugin: { indexTemplatePath: './templates' } };
http.plugin.require('lout', loutConfig, function () {
    http.start(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the issues. Although, now there seems to be an issue with the plugin itself (Plugin missing register() method) but this answers this question.